# NSstring with format error in IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have declared NSString with some string value in ViewdidLoad like..

```
int i=1;
strval=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d",i];
strval=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%@",strval];

NSLog(@"Value %@",strval);
```

it gives correct result as S001, but when i print this same in IBAction like,

```
- (IBAction)stringvalue:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Value %@",strval);
}
```

it gives unknown values each time.Sometimes it throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Please help me..

Comment: `stringValue` method doesn't know about strval. Where are you declaring strval? And How?

Comment: I have declared in header file using property attribute and i have synthesize it in implementation file, stringvalue is just my button click action..

Comment: Update your code please so we can see it all. the .h part, your synthesize.

Comment: You don't ARC, right? Anyway, it is advisable to access properties though the setter only (unless in a getter or setter itself). Use `self.strval = ...`

Comment: In header file i declared as                                //@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *strval;                               In Implementation file I declared as                                         //@synthesize strval;

Comment: So since you are using `retain` you are not using ARC so wheres your initialization of the strval?

Comment: Sorry I am not using ARC

Comment: @trojanfoe has given a good answer then. Mine is for ARC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you aren't using ARC, so the string is being released the next time the autorelease pool drains.  You need to explicitly `retain` it in `viewDidLoad` and explicitly `release` it in your overwridden `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    strval = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", i] retain];

    ....
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [strval release];

    ...

    [super dealloc];
}
```

(I am assuming you've actually declared `strval` as an instance method).

Comment: Actually slightly better would be `strval = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%03d", i];`.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this

in .h

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strval;
```

in .m

```
  @synthesize strval = _strval

  - (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
      int i = 4;
      // ARC
      _strval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %d", i];
      // None ARC
      // strcal = [[NSString alloc] initwithFormat:@"hello %d",i];
      NSLog(@"%@", _strval);
      // Prints "hello 4" in console (TESTED)
  } 

  - (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
  {
      NSLog(@"%@", _strval);
      // Prints "hello 4" in console (TESTED)
  }
```

using ARC. This has been tested and works the way the question has been asked.

Answer (score 3):

in .h

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strval;
```

in .m

```
  @synthesize strval = _strval   

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    self.strval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", i];

    ....
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.strval = nil;

    ...

    [super dealloc];
}
```

This one works either, with ARC and without.

Just one addition: With ARC the statement `[super dealloc];` must be omitted.

Comment: What if he doesn't want `strval` to be changed from outside the class?

Comment: Then he could declare the property in the .m file too in a class extension. Strictly spoken the property could still be accessed from outside but it is not quite "visible".

Comment: Or better still, he could make the `@property` readonly and provide a private setter method within the `.m` file.

Comment: Yes. But when he provides a private setter method then he should care for proper memory management within that too.